# How to disable these pop-ups in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

In Android Studio, sometimes these "callouts" or... "tooltips"(?) pop up on top of the code I'm trying to read, like so:

[image]

How does one opt out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Java`
Make sure your `Show import pop up for:` classed and static methods and fields` are both uncheck. This will prevent the import dialog showing when missing import statement.
Hope that help. ^^

Answer (score 1):

On the bottom right corner, you have an option to change the highlight level to either syntax mode, or None. 
[image]

[image]

Alternatively, you can enable power saver mode as well to disable it, by going to 
File>Power Save Mode